# Python, ChatGPT, RVC V2, TTS, torch, cuda, SpeechRecognition bot

Tags: python, pytorch

I have cobbled together a few python scripts/packages and I am working on a script that my friends and I can talk to and have it talk back using chatGPT and a Jschlatt RVC V2 ai voice model.

so far i have accomplished most of these things, currently i am running into an issue trying to execute ILC for https://huggingface.co/lj1995/VoiceConversionWebUI. I have run into an error that i managed to fix once then never fixed again, nor do i remember how i got around this.
"RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.HalfTensor) should be the same"

New to this whole scene so I will post what i think is needed? let me know if you need more.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Apps\DECtalk-Twitch-TTS-bot-master\custom ai\vcgpt\myinfer-v2-0528.py", line 173, in <module>
    wav_opt=vc_single(0,input_path,f0up_key,None,f0method,index_path,index_rate)
  File "D:\Apps\DECtalk-Twitch-TTS-bot-master\custom ai\vcgpt\myinfer-v2-0528.py", line 139, in vc_single
    audio_opt=vc.pipeline(hubert_model,net_g,sid,audio,input_audio,times,f0_up_key,f0_method,file_index,index_rate,if_f0,filter_radius,tgt_sr,resample_sr,rms_mix_rate,version,protect,f0_file=f0_file)
  File "D:\Apps\DECtalk-Twitch-TTS-bot-master\custom ai\vcgpt\vc_infer_pipeline.py", line 384, in pipeline
    self.vc(
  File "D:\Apps\DECtalk-Twitch-TTS-bot-master\custom ai\vcgpt\vc_infer_pipeline.py", line 185, in vc
    logits = model.extract_features(**inputs)
  File "C:\Users\boolean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\fairseq\models\hubert\hubert.py", line 535, in extract_features
    res = self.forward(
  File "C:\Users\boolean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\fairseq\models\hubert\hubert.py", line 437, in forward
    features = self.forward_features(source)
  File "C:\Users\boolean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\fairseq\models\hubert\hubert.py", line 392, in forward_features
    features = self.feature_extractor(source)
  File "C:\Users\boolean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\boolean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\fairseq\models\wav2vec\wav2vec2.py", line 895, in forward
    x = conv(x)
  File "C:\Users\boolean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\boolean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py", line 217, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "C:\Users\boolean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\boolean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 313, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "C:\Users\boolean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 309, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv1d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.HalfTensor) should be the same
```

and this is the script i made/am running

```
import os, uuid
import simpleaudio as sa
import config
import threading

import openai
import speech_recognition as sr

import keyboard

cont = False

openai.api_key = "boolean"

MODE = "queue"
TMP_DIR = config.settings['TMP_DIR']

message = "test"

keywords = [
    'hey Chad',
    'a Chad',
    'hey slatbot',
    'a slatbot',
    'hey slapbot',
    'a slapbot',
    'hey slap off',
    'a slap off',
    'a SpotBot',
    'hey slap',
    'a swat-bot',
    'a slap',
    'hey swat-bot',
    'hey SpotBot',
    'a Spot',
    'hey Spot',
    'a slack',
    'hey slack',
    'a slackbot',
    'hey slackbot',
    'a chat',
    'hey chat',
    'a chatbot',
    'hey chatbot',
    'play slatbot',
    'play slatbot',
    'play slapbot',
    'play slapbot',
    'play slap off',
    'play slap off',
    'play SpotBot',
    'play slap',
    'play swat-bot',
    'play slap',
    'play swat-bot',
    'play SpotBot',
    'play Spot',
    'play Spot',
    'play slack',
    'play slack',
    'play slackbot',
    'play slackbot',
    'play chat',
    'play chat',
    'play chatbot',
    'play chatbot'
    ]

# Makes temporary dirs if they dont exist
if not os.path.exists(TMP_DIR):
    os.makedirs(TMP_DIR)

def say_single_message(message):
    session = str(uuid.uuid1())
    temp_wav = os.path.join(TMP_DIR, session+'.wav')
    message = message.replace('"', '').replace('&', '').replace('|', '').replace(';', '')
    if os.name == 'nt':
        #print("say.exe -d dtalk_us.dic -w "+temp_wav+" \"[:phoneme on]"+message+"\"")
        os.system("say.exe -d dtalk_us.dic -w "+temp_wav+" \"[:phoneme on]"+message+"\"")
        os.system('py "custom ai/vcgpt/myinfer-v2-0528.py" 0 "'+temp_wav+'" "added_IVF1768_Flat_nprobe_1_v2.index" harvest "'+temp_wav+'" "jschlatt.pth" 0.66 cuda:0 True 3 0 1 0.33')
        #os.system('py "custom ai/vcgpt/infer_web.py" cli_infer jschlatt.pth "'+temp_wav+'" "'+temp_wav+'" added_IVF1768_Flat_nprobe_1_v2.index 0 0 harvest 160 3 0 1 0.78 0.33')
      
    else:
        #print("wine say.exe -d dtalk_us.dic -w "+temp_wav+" \"[:phoneme on]"+message+"\"")
        os.system("wine say.exe -d dtalk_us.dic -w "+temp_wav+" \"[:phoneme on]"+message+"\"")
    wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file(temp_wav)
    play_obj = wave_obj.play()
    play_obj.wait_done()
    os.remove(temp_wav)

def run_singlethread():
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("Listening...")
            audio = r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit=30)
        try:
            prompt = r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-EN", show_all=False)
            print("we heard:", prompt)
            askbot = [
                {"role": "system", "content": "You are an edgy AI Assistant, full of awkward comedy, with a personality somewhat close to a college frat bro."},
                {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
                ]
            if  any(s in prompt for s in keywords):
                print("keyword found")
                print("we asked chat.")
                response_text = askchat(askbot)
                
                print("Chat says:", response_text)
                say_single_message(response_text)
                run_singlethread()
            else:
                print('No keyword detected')
                run_singlethread()
                
        except Exception:
            pass
            run_singlethread()

def run_queue_single():
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("Listening...")
            audio = r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit=30)
            
            try:
                prompt = r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-EN", show_all=False)
                print("we heard:", prompt)
                askbot = [
                    {"role": "system", "content": "You are an edgy AI Assistant, full of awkward comedy, with a personality somewhat close to a college frat bro."},
                    {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
                    ]
                if  any(s in prompt for s in keywords) or cont == True:
                    if cont == False:
                        print("keyword found")
                    else:
                        print("keyword not being looked for")
                    print("we asked chat.")
                    response_text = askchat(askbot)
                    
                    print("Chat says:", response_text)
                    say_single_message(response_text)
                    run_queue_single()
                else:
                    print('No keyword detected')
                    run_queue_single()
                    
                
            except Exception:
                print('There was an error')
                run_queue_single()

def run_multithread():
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("Listening...")
            audio = r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit=30)
            prompt = r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-EN", show_all=False)
            
            try:
                for line in prompt:
                    print("we heard:", prompt)
                    askbot = [
                        {"role": "system", "content": "You are an edgy AI Assistant, full of awkward comedy, with a personality somewhat close to a college frat bro."},
                        {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
                        ]
                    if  any(s in prompt for s in keywords) or cont == True:
                        if cont == False:
                            print("keyword found")
                        else:
                            print("keyword not being looked for")
                        print("we asked chat.")
                        response_text = askchat(askbot)
                        print("Chat says:", response_text)
                        threading.Thread(target=say_single_message, args=(response_text,)).start()
                        run_multithread()
                    else:
                        print('No keyword detected')
                        run_multithread()
                
            except Exception:
                pass
                run_multithread()
            
            

def askchat(askbot):
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages = askbot,
            temperature=0.7,
            max_tokens=300
        )
        response_text = response.choices[0].message.content
        return response_text

def toggle():
    global cont
    if cont == False:
        cont = True
        print("now ignoring keywords")
    else:
        cont = False
        print("now listening to keywords")

def skip():
    sa.stop_all()
    

keyboard.add_hotkey("Page_Up", toggle) # add the hotkey
keyboard.add_hotkey("Page_Down", skip) # add the hotkey


if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    if MODE == 'keepup':
        run_singlethread()
    elif MODE == 'queue':
        run_queue_single()
    elif MODE == 'multi':
        run_multithread()
    else:
        print('Please select a mode by editing the MODE variable ')
```

Let me know what else to add (hopefully i covered up all the sensitive info, and yes my script has a lot of un needed parts, that are left over from testing, keeping them there incase i want to explore them later

gone in loops uninstalling and reinstalling various pip requirement packages, and redownloading specific versions from specific websites to fix errors that got me to this point, now I'm in a loop of doing this getting nowhere

EG.
`pip install torch -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`